# Which layout to use for my application?

Tags: java, layout

I am not sure which layout to use for program that looks like this:
[image]

I am using Eclipse and Window Builder Pro plugin, and know basic about layout managers. What you suggest me for this?

Comment: Go for NetBeans! That is the best IDE I know for dealing with GUIs :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GridLayout().

For instance: `new GridLayout(4,2);`

Apart from that, you can get use of a combination of layouts by well-designing your panels and frame. For instance, you can use GridLayout for a JPanel object, BorderLayout for another JPanel object, arrange the components of these 2 panels internally, then add these 2 panels to a JFrame object which uses another layout, let's say FlowLayout.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a `BorderLayout` for the outmost components, with the "center" the image on the right, and the "left" containing itself a `RowLayout` to contain all the components in a stacked column:

```
 +-----------------+----(BorderLayout)------------+
 |     LEFT        |          CENTER              |
 | +-(RowLayout)-+ |                              |
 | | ROW1        | |                              |
 | +-------------+ |                              |
 | | ROW2        | |                              |
 | +-------------+ |                              |
 | | ...         | |                              |
 | +-------------+ |                              |
 | | ROWn        | |                              |
 | +-------------+ |                              |
 +-----------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: You're right, but why should we use two different layout, combine them in some way e.t.c, when we can simply use GridLayout? And to create that label + field + label stack on the left side, you should put a separate composite in each row of RowLayout.

Comment: In order to design layout you need to know how your window need to react when resizing. In your case, layout can depend on which part of the screen you want to resize when a user resize it's windows. BorderLayout has the advantage of controlling this behavior easily: left/right/top/bottom is fixed, center will grow and shrink.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some easy, yet powerful layout manager, go GridLayout. And use FormLayout for more complex ones. I've also notices 'Next' button in you window, so you should probably take a look at JFace Wizards.